# How to save image as progressive image using paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, optimization, paperclip

How to save image as progressive image using paperclip/Imagemagick?

Code I am using:

```
has_attached_file :photo, {
      :styles => {
          :medium => ["200x200#", :jpg] ,
          :small => ["192x256#", :jpg], 
          :thumb => ["50x50#", :jpg],
          :small_thumb =>["30x30#", :jpg] 
        },
        :convert_options => { 
          :medium => "-quality 60",
          :small => "-quality 60",
          :thumb => "-quality 60",
          :small_thumb => "-quality 60" 
        },
      :default_url => "/assets/default_:style.png" }.merge(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `-interlace Line` in the `convert_options` of your choice.

[Doc states](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interlace) explicitly:

> Use Line or Plane to create an interlaced PNG or GIF or progressive JPEG image.

Comment: Also, i realize that you cant add 'original' in the convert options.